# FetchType LAZY not working for OneToMany assosiation with spring data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity Student and Address.
I am using FetchType.LAZY. But when i fetch student via spring data findById, it fetch address list associated with student.

```
@Table(name = "Student")
```

public class Student {

```
@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "STUDENT_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "STUDENT_ID", sequenceName = "STUDENT_ID_SEQ")
@Column(name="STUDENT_ID")
 private Long id;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private List<Address> address;
```

}

@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "ADDRESS_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ADDRESS_ID", sequenceName = "ADDRESS_ID_SEQ")
@Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
private Long id;

private String desc;
```

}

---

Optional optional=respository.findById(id);
Student s=optional.get();

This is executing two sqls one for student table and second for address table to find associated address of student.

Ideally student should have only student data except associated address.

As we have mentioned Lazy loading it should not fire the second excel.

Comment: In your example I can see FetchType.EAGER Where do you have Lazy?

Comment: If i change LAZY also no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change:
public class Student {

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "STUDENT_ID")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "STUDENT_ID", sequenceName = "STUDENT_ID_SEQ")
@Column(name="STUDENT_ID")
 private Long id;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  mappedBy="student")
private List<Address> address; 
}
```

And :

```
    @Table(name = "Address") public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "ADDRESS_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ADDRESS_ID", sequenceName = "ADDRESS_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String desc;

 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
     public Student student;
    }
```

@JoinColumn lets @OneToMany side in charge of the association, not the best choice, try use the "mappedBy" attribute on the @OneToMany side.